# Why is News.app greyed out in the Finder?

Tags: finder, icon, news.app

I just noticed today that the icon and name for `/Applications/News.app` is greyed out in the Finder.  The appearance is consistent no matter which view I use (icon/list/column), and it persists after restarts and system updates.

News.app is the only app on my system that has this appearance.

I can still launch the app, and it seems to work, although it doesn't load any stories.

Why is News.app greyed out in the Finder?

Screenshot

[image: screenshot of Applications folder showing News.app icon and name greyed out while other icons appear normal]

Answer (score 15):

Figured it out:  I live outside of the regions where Apple News is available, so the app would normally be hidden in the Finder.  However, I have "Show hidden files" enabled in the Finder, so the app is visible but greyed-out.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_(Apple)#History):

> During the 2018 WWDC, Apple announced that the Apple News app would be ported to macOS and be available to users in Australia, United Kingdom, and United States starting in macOS 10.14.<sup>[[9]](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/apple-news-macos-worldwide.html)</sup> The app is installed by default in every region but is not made visible to users outside those three regions.<sup>[[9]](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/apple-news-macos-worldwide.html)</sup>

Comment: I am also outside of those regions, but don't have a hidden News app `ls: /Applications/News.app: No such file or directory` on latest macOS

Comment: @Sybil _News_ is a system application. It would be under `/System/Applications`.